# Javascript - closure - syntax - public members

Tags: javascript, performance, methods, closures

I already read a lot of articles about closure and prototype...but I still have some questions.
I started from this article : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kristoffer/archive/2007/02/13/javascript-prototype-versus-closure-execution-speed.aspx

My question is about to expose public methods:

Is this method :

```
// Closure implementation
function Pixel(x, y){
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.getX = function(){
    return this.x;
  }
  this.getY = function(){
    return this.y;
  }
  this.setX = function(value){
    this.x = value;
  }
  this.setY = function(value){
    this.y = value;
  }
}
```

different from this one:

```
// Closure implementation
function Pixel(x, y){
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
    return {
        getX : function(){
            return this.x;
          },
        getY : function(){
            return this.y;
          },
        setX : function(value){
            this.x = value;
          },
        setY : function(value){
            this.y = value;
          }
    }
}
```

Which one is the best one? And why?

Last question : from the benchmark above, is there a way to use closure to have similar performances than prototype?

tx

Comment: Those examples are not equivalent and neither makes really use of closures. Take the second example and run `(new Pixel(4,2)).getX()`. The return value will be `undefined` instead of `4`. Assuming you fixed that, the biggest difference is that in the second case, the instantiated (returned) object does not inherit from `Pixel.prototype` and tests like `obj instanceof Pixel` would fail.

Comment: The first example is a "class" definition, and the second example does not work at all. That's the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Well there is no "better" implementation.

The second option will yield errors as you cannot call new on it therefore `this` will refer to the window (or whatever scope you are in when the function is defined/called), so do not use it

The second option could use the closure like this :

```
function Pixel(x, y){
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  var that = this;
    return {
        getX : function(){
            return that.x;
          },
        getY : function(){
            return that.y;
          },
        setX : function(value){
            that.x = value;
          },
        setY : function(value){
            that.y = value;
          }
    }
}
```

but this starts to be really ugly, isn't compatible with `prototype` and in my opinion gives too much importance to the privacy problem.

Comment: If you do `var o = new Pixel(10, 20)`, then `o.getX()`, `this` will be the returned object, but `x` and `y` will be undefined.

Comment: You can call any function with `new`. It just has to return an object and if it doesn't, `this` is returned.

Comment: Additionally, the first method with `var` statements would server as a better way to make "private fields".

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things to say.  First of all, this sort of `get`/`set` mechanism is rarely appropriate in Javascript.  This Java construct had to do with
making sure all access to data was through public methods and not through private properties; the Javascript world simply doesn't care.

But let's say that you did want Pixel objects, and you wanted to encapsulate their `x` and `y` data, exposing, let's say, the following two functions:

```
toString(); // String (a representation of this Pixel)
offset(deltaX, deltaY); // Pixel (a new Pixel shifted by deltas from this one)
```

Then you can do it like this:

```
var PixelA = function(x, y) {
    this.x = x; this.y = y;
    this.toString = function() {
        return "(" + this.x + ", " + this.y + ")";
    };
    this.offset = function(deltaX, deltaY) {
        return new PixelA(this.x + deltaX, this.y + deltaY);
    };
};
```

or you can do it like this:

```
var PixelB = function(x, y) {
    this.toString = function() {
        return "(" + x + ", " + y + ")";
    };
    this.offset = function(deltaX, deltaY) {
        return new PixelB(x + deltaX, y + deltaY);
    };
};
```

or you can do it like this:

```
var PixelC = function(x, y) {
    this.x = x; this.y = y;
}
PixelC.prototype.toString = function() {
    return "(" + this.x + ", " + this.y + ")";
};
PixelC.prototype.offset = function(deltaX, deltaY) {
    return new PixelC(this.x + deltaX, this.y + deltaY);
};
```

(**Note**: all are untested.)

`PixelA` is fairly naive.  Our data is not encapsulated; anyone can access or mutate our internal `x` and `y` properties directly.  And it's memory-intensive; every instance of PixelA will have its own copy of the `toString` and `offset` functions.

`PixelB` addresses the first problem.  The internal data is stored in a closure generated by the constructor function.  The `toString` and `offset` functions have access to those variables, but nothing outside can see them directly.  But it offers no relief for the second problem.

`PixelC` addresses the second problem.  Since the `toString` and `offset` functions are stored on the prototype, the instances are not littered with repetitive copies of them.  But the `x` and `y` properties are once again public, and the first problem is back.

I don't know of an option D.  I believe you need to make a choice between encapsulation of your internal state and giving your prototype functions access to that state.  There are many different sytactic contortions you can go through to try to fix this; but none really address this underlying issue.  You can perform certain optimizations in either direction, but the problem is fundamental.

I'd love to be proven wrong.

As to the performance question: there is no way that the closure-based construction could every be as fast as the prototype-based construction.  Think of all the work that has to be done to assign all those properties for each instance in the closure-based version, work that simply doesn't have to be done in the prototype-based one.  Now it's possible that closure-based property access will be faster...